# React Native renderRow error: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'e.id')

Tags: listview, react-native, undefined, react-native-listview

Trying to renderRow in a ListView in react native. The list is populated from the results of a user search. There is a debounce of 400 ms to keep the number of requests down. The problem is if I setState while the renderRow is happening on the last state Change the app will crash with undefined fetching the rowData.id. I've tried to catch if results are 'undefined' or null, through a serious of if statements, also checking `this.state.dataSource.getRowCount() === 0` before rendering the ListView at all to try and avoid this. It is a listView with multiple sections and headers.

```
 renderRow: function(
    rowData: Object,
    sectionID: number | string,
    rowID: number | string,
    highlightRowFunc: (sectionID: ?number | string, rowID: ?number | string) => void,      
  ) {
    if(rowData) {
      switch(sectionID) {
        case GLOBAL.PATHWAYTITLE:
        if(rowData){
          var content = <PMSearchPathwayCell
            refs="cell"
            key={rowData.pathway_id}
            onSelect={() => this.selectPathway(rowData) }
            onSelectMore={() => this.onSelectMore(rowData) }
            onHighlight={() => highlightRowFunc(sectionID, rowID) }
            onUnhighlight={() => highlightRowFunc(null, null) }
            pathway={rowData}
            /> 
        }
            break;
        case GLOBAL.PICMONICTITLE:
          if (rowData == null) {
            console.log(rowData.id);
          }
          if(rowData) {
          var content = <PMSearchCardCell
            refs="cell"
            key={rowData.id}
            onSelect={() => this.selectCard(rowData) }
            onSelectMore={() => this.onSelectMore(rowData) }
            onHighlight={() => highlightRowFunc(sectionID, rowID) }
            onUnhighlight={() => highlightRowFunc(null, null) }
            card={rowData}
            />
          }
            break;
            //Default added. Since we provide the array of pathwaytitle and picmonictitle this isn't a scenario that we 
            //should ever encounter. 
        default:
        console.log("SectionID for rowRender not set!");
        var content = <Text>Not Available</Text>
            break;
      }
    } 

    return (
      <View>
      {content}
      </View>
    );
  },
```